# Smooth $r$-form as the exterior product of $r$ $1$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional manifold and $\alpha$ a smooth $r$-form in $M$. It is clear that $\alpha$ can be written locally as $\alpha=\alpha_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_r$ for some $1$-forms $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r$ just by considering its expression in a local chart of $M$.

In general, can we have this descomposition $\alpha=\alpha_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_r$ in the whole manifold? Maybe with the use of bump functions?

Comment: In Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$, how do we write $dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_2 \wedge dx_3 + dx_3 \wedge dx_1$ as $\alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2$?

Comment: @aschepler $(dx_1 - dx_3)\wedge(dx_2 - dx_1)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In looking for the easiest counter example, my initial answer was incorrect. However, it is still not true, even locally. For example, if we take $dx\wedge dy+dz\wedge dw$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$, you cannot write this as a wedge of $1$-forms, but trying to is probably a good exercise.